# LOAD segment with RWX permissions, Linker add writable attribute after use align in section

Tags: linker, ld, riscv, binutils

My binutils version:
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.39
and there is a new warn 'LOAD segment with RWX permissions'

here is the linker script

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
ENTRY( _start )

MEMORY
{
    /* Fake ROM area */
    rom (rxa) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 512K
    ram (wxa) : ORIGIN = 0x80080000, LENGTH = 512K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .init :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
    } >rom AT>rom
    
    .text :
    {
        *(.text.unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
        *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
        *(.text .text.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    } >rom AT>rom
    
    .fini :
    {
        KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
        _etext = .;
    } >rom AT>rom

    .rodata.align :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _rodata = .;
    } >rom AT>rom

    .rodata.start :
    {
        _rodata_lma = LOADADDR(.rodata.start);
    } >rom AT>rom

    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rdata)
        *(.rodata .rodata.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.r.*)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erodata = .;
    } >rom AT>rom

    .data.align :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _data = .;
    } >ram AT>rom

    .data.start :
    {
        _data_lma = LOADADDR(.data.start);
    } >ram AT>rom

    .data :
    {
        *(.data .data.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
        . = ALIGN(8);
        PROVIDE( __global_pointer$ = . + 0x800 );
        *(.sdata .sdata.*)
        *(.sdata2 .sdata2.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.s.*)
        . = ALIGN(8);
        *(.srodata.cst16)
        *(.srodata.cst8)
        *(.srodata.cst4)
        *(.srodata.cst2)
        *(.srodata .srodata.*)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } >ram AT>rom

    .bss.align :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss = .;
    } >ram AT>rom

    .bss.start :
    {
        _bss_lma = LOADADDR(.bss.start);
    } >ram AT>rom

    .bss :
    {
        *(.sbss*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.sb.*)
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;
    } >ram AT>rom

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _end = .;

    .stack :
    {
        . = ALIGN(16);
        . += __stack_size;
        _stack_top = .;
    } >ram AT>ram
}
```

I found that if I change the rodata.align section as below, the problem can fix.

```
    .rodata.align ALIGN(4):
    {
        _rodata = .;
    } >rom AT>rom
```

readelf -Sl original.elf

```
There are 24 section headers, starting at offset 0x29a08:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .init             PROGBITS        80000000 001000 000076 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        80000100 001100 00b6f2 00  AX  0   0 256
  [ 3] .rodata.align     NOBITS          8000b7f2 00c7f2 000002 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 4] .rodata           PROGBITS        8000b7f4 00c7f4 0009c4 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 5] .data.align       PROGBITS        80080000 00e9d0 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 6] .data             PROGBITS        80080000 00e000 0009d0 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 7] .bss.align        NOBITS          800809d0 000000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 8] .bss              NOBITS          800809d0 00e9d0 011e08 00  WA  0   0 16
  [ 9] .stack            NOBITS          800927d8 00f7d8 000134 00  WA  0   0  1
  [10] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 00e9d0 00002d 01  MS  0   0  1
  [11] .riscv.attributes RISCV_ATTRIBUTE 00000000 00e9fd 00002f 00      0   0  1
  [12] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 00ea2c 003a54 00      0   0  1
  [13] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 012480 0010bc 00      0   0  1
  [14] .debug_loclists   PROGBITS        00000000 01353c 0097da 00      0   0  1
  [15] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 01cd16 000178 00      0   0  1
  [16] .debug_rnglists   PROGBITS        00000000 01ce8e 001154 00      0   0  1
  [17] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 01dfe2 007949 00      0   0  1
  [18] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 02592b 0008ed 01  MS  0   0  1
  [19] .debug_line_str   PROGBITS        00000000 026218 000388 01  MS  0   0  1
  [20] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 0265a0 000288 00      0   0  4
  [21] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 026828 002020 10     22 343  4
  [22] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 028848 0010bf 00      0   0  1
  [23] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 029907 0000fe 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x80000000
There are 4 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  RISCV_ATTRIBUT 0x00e9fd 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0002f 0x00000 R   0x1
  LOAD           0x001000 0x80000000 0x80000000 0x0c1b8 0x0c1b8 RWE 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00e000 0x80080000 0x8000c1b8 0x009d0 0x127d8 RW  0x1000
  LOAD           0x0007d8 0x800927d8 0x800927d8 0x00000 0x00134 RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .riscv.attributes 
   01     .init .text .rodata.align .rodata 
   02     .data .bss.align .bss 
   03     .stack
```

readelf -Sl modify.elf

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .init             PROGBITS        80000000 001000 000076 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        80000100 001100 00b6f2 00  AX  0   0 256
  [ 3] .rodata           PROGBITS        8000b7f4 00c7f4 0009c4 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .data.align       PROGBITS        80080000 00e9d0 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 5] .data             PROGBITS        80080000 00e000 0009d0 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 6] .bss.align        NOBITS          800809d0 000000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 7] .bss              NOBITS          800809d0 00e9d0 011e08 00  WA  0   0 16
  [ 8] .stack            NOBITS          800927d8 00f7d8 000134 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 9] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 00e9d0 00002d 01  MS  0   0  1
  [10] .riscv.attributes RISCV_ATTRIBUTE 00000000 00e9fd 00002f 00      0   0  1
  [11] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 00ea2c 003a54 00      0   0  1
  [12] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 012480 0010bc 00      0   0  1
  [13] .debug_loclists   PROGBITS        00000000 01353c 0097da 00      0   0  1
  [14] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 01cd16 000178 00      0   0  1
  [15] .debug_rnglists   PROGBITS        00000000 01ce8e 001154 00      0   0  1
  [16] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 01dfe2 007949 00      0   0  1
  [17] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 02592b 0008ed 01  MS  0   0  1
  [18] .debug_line_str   PROGBITS        00000000 026218 000388 01  MS  0   0  1
  [19] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 0265a0 000288 00      0   0  4
  [20] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 026828 002010 10     21 342  4
  [21] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 028838 0010bf 00      0   0  1
  [22] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0298f7 0000f0 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x80000000
There are 4 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  RISCV_ATTRIBUT 0x00e9fd 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0002f 0x00000 R   0x1
  LOAD           0x001000 0x80000000 0x80000000 0x0c1b8 0x0c1b8 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00e000 0x80080000 0x8000c1b8 0x009d0 0x127d8 RW  0x1000
  LOAD           0x0007d8 0x800927d8 0x800927d8 0x00000 0x00134 RW  0x1000
```

Why the align command cause the LOAD section has a writable attribute?

I found that if I change the rodata.align section as below, the problem can fix.

```
    .rodata.align ALIGN(4):
    {
        _rodata = .;
    } >rom AT>rom
```

Comment: What are the 2 bytes that are in the `.rodata.align` in the first one?  They are marked `NOBITS`; they don't appear in the 2nd output and are not accounted for by an increase in size of `.rodata`. I'd  be looking at`NOBITS`, since then that requires initialization by zeroing?